# Is it possible to create a VRP solution using NetworkX?

Tags: python, vehicle-routing, optapy

[image: DummyNetwork]
[image]
Please refer to the dummy network created using networkX.

1. I have created a dummy network of 50 nodes (incomplete graph) in Python using the networkX package. The dummy network of nodes is represented by the above diagrams diagrams.
2. I have randomly chosen Nodes AJ, A, G, R as vehicle starting points/depots.
3. I have randomly chosen F, AQ, AA as the  dumping zones.
4. Each edge has certain weights, which is a representation of the amount of waste a vehicle can collect from that node.
5. Each depot has fixed number of vehicles, and each vehicle have a fixed carrying capacity, beyond which it will dump the waste to the nearest dumping zone. After dumping the waste, the vehicle can return to the original start depot (if there's no more waste left to clean)

Here the fixed conditions are as follow:

1. Network is fixed.
2. Depot & Dumping zone locations are fixed.
3. Number of vehicle in each dumping zone is fixed.
4. Carrying capacity of each vehicle is fixed for now.
5. Edge weight represents the amount/volume of waste present in a edge.

How to build this solution using OptaPy ?

EDIT:

Let's stay, a vehicle starts from Node R. Based on the waste accumulation, let's say it traverses this path -- R - Q - O - N - L - K - J. Let's say that at Node J, the vehicle capacity will max out, then it should check from J which is the nearest dumping zone. The vehicle will see that F is the nearest dumping zone, so it will go to F, dump the waste and re-start it's operation from F. Let's say from F, the vehicle takes another path -- F - G - U - V - W - X. Let's say that the same vehicles capacity is maxed out at X. Then it will see that the nearest dumping zone from Z is AA, hence it will go there and dump the waste. Now if there's no longer waste left to be cleaned, the vehicle can get back to its starting position which is R.

Answer (score 2):

I would model the problem as below using OptaPy:

- The edges that can be collected from will be an `@problem_fact` with graph_nodes ids (assuming str) and weight fields:

```py
@optapy.problem_fact
class Edge:
    graph_from_node: str
    graph_to_node: str
    weight: int
    
    def __init__(self, graph_from_node: str, graph_to_node: str, weight: int):
        self.graph_from_node = graph_from_node
        self.graph_to_node = graph_to_node
        self.weight = weight
```

- The `@planning_entity` is a vehicle, with a fixed depot and carrying capacity, and a `@planning_list_variable` of `Edge`:

```py
@optapy.planning_entity
class Vehicle:
    capacity: int
    depot: str
    visited_edges_list: List[Edge]

    def __init__(self, capacity: int, depot: str, visited_edges_list=None):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.depot = depot
        self.visited_edges_list = [] if visited_edges_list is None else visited_edges_list

    @optapy.planning_list_variable(Edge, ['edge_range'])
    def get_visited_edges_list(self):
        return self.visited_edges_list

    def set_visited_edges_list(self, visited_edges_list):
        return self.visited_edges_list
```

- There would be a NetworkInfo `@problem_fact`, which can be used to query dumping zones and get the full network:

```py
@optapy.problem_fact
class NetworkInfo:
    graph: Graph
    dumping_zones: List[str]

    def __init__(self, graph: Graph, dumping_zones: List[str]):
        self.graph = graph
        self.dumping_zones = dumping_zones
```

- The `@planning_solution` would store the NetworkInfo, Edge, Vehicle and the solution's score:

```py
from optapy.score import HardSoftScore

@optapy.planning_solution
class VRPSolution:
    def __init__(self, network_info: NetworkInfo, vehicle_list: List[Vehicle], edge_list: List[Edge], score=None):
        self.network_info = network_info
        self.vehicle_list = vehicle_list
        self.edge_list = edge_list
        self.score = score
    
    @problem_fact_property(NetworkInfo)
    def get_network_info(self):
        return self.network_info

    @planning_entity_collection_property(Vehicle)
    def get_vehicle_list(self):
        return self.vehicle_list

    @problem_fact_collection_property(Edge)
    @value_range_provider('edge_range')
    def get_customer_list(self):
        return self.edge_list

    @planning_score(HardSoftScore)
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score
```

You would create the initial planning problem like this:

```py
problem = VRPSolution(NetworkInfo(my_graph, ['F', 'AQ', 'AA']),
                      [
                        Vehicle(10, 'AJ'),
                        Vehicle(15, 'A'),
                        Vehicle(5, 'G'),
                        Vehicle(15, 'R'),
                        # ...
                      ],
                      [
                        Edge('AM', 'AN', 3),
                        Edge('AW', 'AV', 4),
                        Edge('P', 'Q', 1),
                        # ...
                      ])
```

You would put your constraints into a `@constraint_provider` function:

```py
@optapy.constraint_provider
def vehicle_routing_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        over_capacity(constraint_factory),
        # other constraints
    ]
```

for example, `over_capacity` would be written like this:

```py
def get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle: Vehicle):
    total = 0
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        total += edge.weight
    return total
        

def over_capacity(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
             .filter(lambda vehicle: get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle) > vehicle.capacity)
             .penalize('Over Capacity', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                       lambda vehicle: get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle) - vehicle.capacity)
    )
```

My guess is you also want to minimize distance. I will assume the distance function = shortest path between edges as given by networkx:

```
def get_vehicle_path_total_distance(vehicle: Vehicle, network_info: NetworkInfo):
    current_node = vehicle.depot
    total = 0
    G = network_info.graph
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        total += nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=current_node, target=edge.graph_from_node)
        current_node = edge.graph_to_node
    shortest_path_length_from_current = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=current_node)
    best_dumping_zone = None
    # best_dumping_zone_path_length = float('inf')
    # Workaround for https://github.com/optapy/optapy/issues/134
    best_dumping_zone_path_length = 999999999999.999
    for dumping_zone in network_info.dumping_zones:
        if shortest_path_length_from_current[dumping_zone] < best_dumping_zone_path_length:
              best_dumping_zone_path_length = shortest_path_length_from_current[dumping_zone]
              best_dumping_zone = dumping_zone
    total += best_dumping_zone_path_length
    total += nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=best_dumping_zone, target=vehicle.depot)
    return total
        

def minimize_distance(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
             .join(NetworkInfo)
             .penalize('Minimize Distance', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT,
                       get_vehicle_path_total_distance)
    )
```

(note: this does not take into consideration the "Number of vehicle in each dumping zone is fixed." constraint. If you want the dumping zone to be a planning variable, you currently need to use a chained model (https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#chainedPlanningVariable) until https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2755 is fixed). If you are doing overconstrained planning (i.e. not enough vehicles to pick up all the garbage in one run), you can change the score type to `HardMediumSoftScore`, and add a new field to vehicle `is_extra`. If the field `is_extra` is True, the vehicle is ignored by the `over_capacity` and `minimize_distance` constraints, and you'll add a new constraint that penalize by `HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_MEDIUM` for each edge in the extra vehicle's visited_edge_list.

Comment: Hello @Christopher, thank you so much for providing such details. I have few questions though regarding the implementation. Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong. I have pasted the code in the below section. Can you kindly check?

Comment: I answered in the comments of your answer; there were some bugs in the above code that I now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for providing a detailed implementation. I have slightly modified your code, but while running the solver, I am getting an error message as below :

```
*** RuntimeError: An error occurred during solving. This can occur when functions take the wrong number of parameters (ex: a setter that does not take exactly one parameter) or by a function returning an incompatible return type (ex: returning a str in a filter, which expects a bool). This can also occur when an exception is raised when evaluating constraints/getters/setters.
```

I have created a NetworkX graph object, and I am currently trying to build the solution on top it. Below is the code for the same. Can you kindly run this code and check if you are able to replicate the same at your end as well? I also have a question related to this implementation.

1. How are you handling the distance matrices? In the implementation, will it automatically take into consideration the distances based on the NetworkX graph object that we create? Or do we need to write a function to compute the distances explicitly?
2. For 'visited_edges_list', what should be the expected input? For each vehicle, do we need to provide a constant list of all the edges? Or we must provide only those edge list which the vehicle can visit?

NOTE : The edge weights represent the waste that needs to be collected from that edge.

EDIT: The runtime error problem was solved, based on the changes suggested by you. I am pasting the latest code, and some outputs to get more clarity on certain questions.

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.classes.graph import Graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import optapy
from optapy.score import HardMediumSoftScore
from optapy.constraint import ConstraintFactory
from optapy.types import Duration
from optapy import solver_factory_create
from typing import List

random_seed = 43
rnd = np.random
rnd.seed(random_seed)


#Configure the nodes and edges of Graph G
nodes_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
              'AA','AB','AC','AD','AE','AF','AG','AH','AI','AJ','AK','AL','AM','AN','AO','AP','AQ','AR','AS','AT','AU','AV','AW','AX']

weights = [('A', 'B', 1), 
          ('B', 'C', 2), 
          ('C', 'D', 5),('C', 'AD', 1) ,
          ('D', 'E', 7), 
          ('E', 'F', 4), ('E', 'AX', 1),
          ('F', 'G', 1), 
          ('G', 'H', 1), ('G', 'U', 8),
          ('H', 'I', 1),
          ('I', 'J', 1),
          ('J', 'K', 1), ('J', 'P', 1),
          ('K', 'L', 1),
          ('L', 'M', 1), ('L', 'N', 1),
          ('N', 'O', 1), 
          ('O', 'P', 1),
          ('P', 'Q', 1),
          ('Q', 'R', 1), ('Q', 'S', 1),
          ('P', 'Q', 1),
          ('S', 'T', 1),
          ('U', 'V', 9),
          ('V', 'W', 1), ('V', 'AU', 1),
          ('W', 'X', 1),
          ('X', 'Y', 1), ('X', 'AB', 1),
          ('Y', 'Z', 1),
          ('Z', 'AA', 1),
          ('AB', 'AC', 1),
          ('AD', 'AE', 1),
          ('AE', 'AF', 10),
          ('AF', 'AG', 15),
          ('AG', 'AH', 1),
          ('AH', 'AI', 1), ('AH', 'AK', 1),
          ('AI', 'AJ', 1),
          ('AK', 'AL', 3),
          ('AL', 'AM', 1),
          ('AM', 'AN', 3), ('AM', 'AV', 1),
          ('AN', 'AO', 1), ('AN', 'AQ', 1),
          ('AO', 'AP', 1),
          ('AQ', 'AR', 1),
          ('AR', 'AS', 1),
          ('AV', 'AT', 1),
          ('AT', 'AU', 1),
          ('AV', 'AW', 4),
          ('AW', 'AX', 6)]

def create_graph_network(nodes_list, weights):
    """
    This function generates and plots a graph object by taking nodes list and edges as input.
    """
    G = nx.Graph()
    G.add_nodes_from(nodes_list)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from(weights)
    pos=nx.spring_layout(G, seed=random_seed)
    nx.draw(G, pos, with_labels=True)
    edge_weight =(nx.get_edge_attributes(G,'weight'))
    nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels = edge_weight)
    plt.axis('on')
    plt.show()
    return G, pos


#The edges from where sand can be collecyed from, will be an @problem_fact with graph_nodes ids and weight fields:
@optapy.problem_fact
class Edge:
    graph_from_node: str
    graph_to_node: str
    weight: int
    
    def __init__(self, graph_from_node: str, graph_to_node: str, weight: int):
        self.graph_from_node = graph_from_node
        self.graph_to_node = graph_to_node
        self.weight = weight
    

#The @planning_entity is a vehicle, with a fixed depot and carrying capacity, and a @planning_list_variable of Edge:
@optapy.planning_entity
class Vehicle:
    idx : int
    capacity: int
    depot: str
    visited_edges_list: List[Edge]

    def __init__(self, capacity: int, depot: str, visited_edges_list=None):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.depot = depot
        self.visited_edges_list = [] if visited_edges_list is None else visited_edges_list

    @optapy.planning_list_variable(Edge, ['edge_range'])
    def get_visited_edges_list(self):
        return self.visited_edges_list

    def set_visited_edges_list(self, visited_edges_list):
        return self.visited_edges_list
    
#There would be a NetworkInfo @problem_fact, which can be used to query dumping zones and get the full network:
@optapy.problem_fact
class NetworkInfo:
    graph: Graph
    dumping_zones: List[str]

    def __init__(self, graph: Graph, dumping_zones: List[str]):
        self.graph = graph
        self.dumping_zones = dumping_zones
        
#The @planning_solution would store the NetworkInfo, Edge, Vehicle and the solution's score:
@optapy.planning_solution
class VRPSolution:
    def __init__(self, network_info: NetworkInfo, vehicle_list: List[Vehicle], edge_list: List[Edge], score=None):
        self.network_info = network_info
        self.vehicle_list = vehicle_list
        self.edge_list = edge_list
        self.score = score
    
    @optapy.problem_fact_property(NetworkInfo)
    def get_network_info(self):
        return self.network_info

    @optapy.planning_entity_collection_property(Vehicle)
    def get_vehicle_list(self):
        return self.vehicle_list

    @optapy.problem_fact_collection_property(Edge)
    @optapy.value_range_provider('edge_range')
    def get_customer_list(self):
        return self.edge_list

    @optapy.planning_score(HardMediumSoftScore)
    def get_score(self):
        return self.score

    def set_score(self, score):
        self.score = score


def get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle: Vehicle):
    total = 0
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        total += edge.weight
    return total
        
#Constraint to specify that the waste collected by the vehicle should not exceed the maximum carrying capacity for each vehicle
def over_capacity(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
             .filter(lambda vehicle: get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle) > vehicle.capacity)
             .penalize('Over Capacity', HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD,
                       lambda vehicle: get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle) - vehicle.capacity)
    )

#Constraint to specify that the priority for a vehilce is to clear the maximum waste.
def maximize_waste_collection(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
             .reward('maximize weight', HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, lambda vehicle: get_vehicle_total_weight(vehicle))
    )

#Constraint to specify that the vehicle travel distance is minimized
def get_vehicle_path_total_distance(vehicle: Vehicle, network_info: NetworkInfo):
    current_node = vehicle.depot
    total = 0
    G = network_info.graph
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        total += nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=current_node, target=edge.graph_from_node)
        current_node = edge.graph_to_node
    shortest_path_length_from_current = nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=current_node)
    best_dumping_zone = None
    best_dumping_zone_path_length = 999999999999.999
    for dumping_zone in network_info.dumping_zones:
        if shortest_path_length_from_current[dumping_zone] < best_dumping_zone_path_length:
              best_dumping_zone_path_length = shortest_path_length_from_current[dumping_zone]
              best_dumping_zone = dumping_zone
    total += best_dumping_zone_path_length
    total += nx.shortest_path_length(G, source=best_dumping_zone, target=vehicle.depot)
    return total
        
#Constraint to specify that the vehicle travel distance is minimized
def minimize_distance(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return (
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
             .join(NetworkInfo)
             .penalize('Minimize Distance', HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, get_vehicle_path_total_distance)
    )

#Constraint to specify that vehicles should only travel between adjacent nodes.
def is_invalid_path(vehicle: Vehicle):
    current = vehicle.depot
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        if edge.graph_from_node != current: 
            return True
        current = edge.graph_to_node
    return False
    
#Constraint to specify that vehicles should only travel between adjacent nodes.
def force_adjacent_nodes(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return(
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
        .filter(lambda vehicle: is_invalid_path(vehicle))
        .penalize('invalid path', HardMediumSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
        )

@optapy.constraint_provider
def vehicle_routing_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        force_adjacent_nodes(constraint_factory),
        over_capacity(constraint_factory),
        minimize_distance(constraint_factory),
        #maximize_waste_collection(constraint_factory),
    ]


#Configurations

#Configure Dumping Zones
dumping_zones_list = ['F', 'AQ', 'AA']

#Configure Graph
G, pos = create_graph_network(nodes_list, weights)
node_list = list(G.nodes())
NetworkInfo_obj = NetworkInfo(G, dumping_zones_list)

#Configure Vehicles and their corresponding capacitites and depots
v1 = Vehicle(25, 'AS')
v2 = Vehicle(25,'AS')
v3 = Vehicle(25, 'A')
v4 = Vehicle(25, 'A')
v5 = Vehicle(25, 'R')
v6 = Vehicle(25, 'R')

# v1 = Vehicle(75, 'AS')
# v2 = Vehicle(75,'A')

#veh_list = [v1, v2, v4, v5, v7, v10, v11, v12]
veh_list = [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6]

e1 = Edge('A', 'B', 1)
e2 = Edge('B', 'C', 2)
e3 = Edge('C', 'D', 5)
e4 = Edge('C', 'AD', 1)
e5 = Edge('D', 'E', 7)
e6 = Edge('E', 'F', 4)
e7 = Edge('E', 'AX', 1)
e8 = Edge('F', 'G', 1)
e9 = Edge('G', 'H', 1)
e10 = Edge('G', 'U', 8)
e11 = Edge('H', 'I', 1)
e12 = Edge('I', 'J', 1)
e13 = Edge('J', 'K', 1)
e14 = Edge('J', 'P', 1)
e15 = Edge('K', 'L', 1)
e16 = Edge('L', 'M', 1)
e17 = Edge('L', 'N', 1)
e18 = Edge('N', 'O', 1)
e19 = Edge('O', 'P', 1)
e20 = Edge('P', 'Q', 1)
e21 = Edge('Q', 'R', 1)
e22 = Edge('Q', 'S', 1)
e23 = Edge('S', 'T', 1)
e24 = Edge('U', 'V', 9)
e25 = Edge('V', 'W', 1)
e26 = Edge('V', 'AU', 1)
e27 = Edge('W', 'X', 1)
e28 = Edge('X', 'Y', 1)
e29 = Edge('X', 'AB', 1)
e30 = Edge('Y', 'Z', 1)
e31 = Edge('Z', 'AA', 1)
e32 = Edge('AB', 'AC', 1)
e33 = Edge('AD', 'AE', 1)
e34 = Edge('AE', 'AF', 10)
e35 = Edge('AF', 'AG', 15)
e36 = Edge('AG', 'AH', 1)
e37 = Edge('AH', 'AI', 1)
e38 = Edge('AH', 'AK', 1)
e39 = Edge('AI', 'AJ', 1)
e40 = Edge('AK', 'AL', 3)
e41 = Edge('AL', 'AM', 1)
e42 = Edge('AM', 'AN', 3)
e43 = Edge('AM', 'AV', 1)
e44 = Edge('AN', 'AO', 1)
e45 = Edge('AN', 'AQ', 1)
e46 = Edge('AO', 'AP', 1)
e47 = Edge('AQ', 'AR', 1)
e48 = Edge('AR', 'AS', 1)
e49 = Edge('AT', 'AV', 1)
e50 = Edge('AT', 'AU', 1)
e51 = Edge('AV', 'AW', 4)
e52 = Edge('AW', 'AX', 6)

edge_list = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, e11, e12, e13, e14, e15, e16, e17, e18, e19, e20, e21, 
              e22, e23, e24, e25, e26, e27, e28, e29, e30, e31, e32, e33, e34, e35, e36, e37, e38, e39, e40, 
              e41, e42, e43, e44, e45, e46, e47, e48, e49, e50, e51, e52]


# edge_list = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, e9, e10, e11]

problem = VRPSolution(NetworkInfo_obj, veh_list, edge_list)

#Print the solution
#timeout = 36000
timeout = 1800
solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig()
solver_config.withSolutionClass(VRPSolution).withEntityClasses(Vehicle).withConstraintProviderClass(vehicle_routing_constraints).withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))

all_edges = list(G.edges())
total_weights = []

for edge in all_edges:
    total_weights.append(G.get_edge_data(edge[0], edge[1])['weight'])
        
total_weights = sum(total_weights)
print("Total Volume of Waste: ", total_weights)


total_capacity_of_vehicles = sum([v.capacity for v in veh_list])

if total_capacity_of_vehicles < total_weights:
    print("Solution is not feasible. Please assign more vehicles or more carrying capacity")
else:
    solution = solver_factory_create(solver_config).buildSolver().solve(problem)
    
    print("Final Score --------------------------- ")
    print(solution.get_score())
    
    
#OUTPUT

vehicle_visited_edges = []
vehicle_visited_nodes = []
vehicle_predicted_route = []

ctr = 1
for vehicle in solution.get_vehicle_list():
    print("Vehicle : ", ctr)
    ctr += 1
    print("Depot : ", vehicle.depot)
    print("Vehicle Capacity : ", vehicle.capacity)

    edges  = vehicle.visited_edges_list
    
    route_path = []
    total_weight = []
    edge_list = []
    visited_node_list = []

    
    for edge in edges:
        print("Edge : ({},{}), Weight : {}".format(edge.graph_from_node, edge.graph_to_node, edge.weight))
        edge_list.append(("{}".format(edge.graph_from_node), "{}".format(edge.graph_to_node)))
        visited_node_list.append(edge.graph_from_node)
        visited_node_list.append(edge.graph_to_node)
        total_weight.append(edge.weight)
        
    print("Visited Edges : ", edge_list)
    print("Visited Nodes : ", visited_node_list)
        
    visited_node_list = list(set(visited_node_list))
    veh_depot = vehicle.depot
    path_dict = dict()
    
    for d_zone in dumping_zones_list:
        all_paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, veh_depot, d_zone)
        for p in list(all_paths):
            ctr_ele = 0
            for ele in visited_node_list:
                if(ele in p):
                    ctr_ele += 1
            
            path_dict[ctr_ele] = p
        
    predicted_route = path_dict[max(path_dict.keys())]
    vehicle_visited_edges.append(edge_list)
    vehicle_visited_nodes.append(visited_node_list)
    vehicle_predicted_route.append(predicted_route)

    print("Vehicle Route : ", predicted_route)
    print("Total Weight of Collected Waste : ", sum(total_weight))
    print()
    
    
vehicle_num = 2

#Run the below two blocks separately

#BLOCK 1 : Display all the visited edges by the vehicle
visited_nodes = vehicle_visited_nodes[vehicle_num-1]
visited_edges = vehicle_visited_edges[vehicle_num-1]
pos=nx.spring_layout(G, seed=random_seed)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=visited_nodes,node_color='g')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=visited_edges,edge_color='r',width=3)

#BLOCK 2 : Display the predicted route for a vehicle
pos=nx.spring_layout(G, seed=random_seed)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels = True)
predicted_route = vehicle_predicted_route[vehicle_num-1]
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,nodelist=predicted_route,node_color='g')
```

OUTPUT :

```
Vehicle :  1
Depot :  AJ
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Edge : AI-AJ, Weight : 1
Edge : AH-AI, Weight : 1
Edge : AF-AG, Weight : 15
Edge : AG-AH, Weight : 1
Edge : AH-AK, Weight : 1
Edge : AK-AL, Weight : 3
Edge : AL-AM, Weight : 1
Edge : AN-AO, Weight : 1
Edge : AO-AP, Weight : 1
Edge : AN-AQ, Weight : 1
Edge : AQ-AR, Weight : 1
Edge : AR-AS, Weight : 1
Vehicle Route :  ['AI', 'AH', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AK', 'AL', 'AN', 'AO', 'AN', 'AQ', 'AR']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  28

Vehicle :  2
Depot :  A
Vehicle Capacity :  15
Edge : A-B, Weight : 1
Edge : B-C, Weight : 2
Edge : C-D, Weight : 5
Edge : D-E, Weight : 7
Vehicle Route :  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  15

Vehicle :  3
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  10
Edge : J-K, Weight : 1
Edge : I-J, Weight : 1
Edge : H-I, Weight : 1
Edge : G-H, Weight : 1
Edge : F-G, Weight : 1
Edge : E-AX, Weight : 1
Edge : E-F, Weight : 4
Vehicle Route :  ['J', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'F', 'E', 'E']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  10

Vehicle :  4
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  50
Edge : Q-S, Weight : 1
Edge : S-T, Weight : 1
Edge : Q-R, Weight : 1
Edge : C-AD, Weight : 1
Edge : P-Q, Weight : 1
Edge : O-P, Weight : 1
Edge : K-L, Weight : 1
Edge : L-N, Weight : 1
Edge : N-O, Weight : 1
Edge : L-M, Weight : 1
Edge : J-P, Weight : 1
Edge : G-U, Weight : 8
Edge : U-V, Weight : 9
Edge : W-X, Weight : 1
Edge : X-AB, Weight : 1
Edge : AB-AC, Weight : 1
Edge : X-Y, Weight : 1
Edge : Y-Z, Weight : 1
Edge : Z-AA, Weight : 1
Edge : V-AU, Weight : 1
Edge : AT-AU, Weight : 1
Edge : V-W, Weight : 1
Edge : AT-AV, Weight : 1
Edge : AM-AN, Weight : 3
Edge : AM-AV, Weight : 1
Edge : AV-AW, Weight : 4
Edge : AW-AX, Weight : 6
Edge : AD-AE, Weight : 1
Edge : AE-AF, Weight : 10
Vehicle Route :  ['Q', 'S', 'Q', 'C', 'P', 'O', 'K', 'L', 'N', 'L', 'J', 'G', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'AB', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'V', 'AT', 'V', 'AT', 'AM', 'AM', 'AV', 'AW', 'AD', 'AE']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  63
```

If you look at the above outputs,

For Vehicle 1, I have assigned a maximum carrying capacity of 25 units. So that means as soon as the vehicle capacity is reached, it should not collect any further waste. But in this case, Vehicle 1 is collecting 28 units of waste (where it's defined capacity is 25 units). I have added the *over_capacity* constraint according to your suggestion, to handle this scenario. However, the total waste collected by the vehicle is exceeding it's carrying capacity. Same happens for Vehicle 4, the total capacity of the vehicle is 50, however it is seen to collect 63 units of waste.

1. What changes do I need to perform, to make sure that the total waste collected by the vehicle strictly doesn't exceed it's carrying capacity?
2. Is there any way to prioritize the order of the usage of constraints? For example, if I have a choice between minimizing the distance travelled by vehicle versus maximizing the amount of waste clearance (even if the distance is more), how do I prioritize the constraints so that the vehicle decides to pick up more waste rather than minimizing the distance? A workaround may be to use one constraint and not use the other. But if we want to use both the constraints and want to prioritize one over the other, how do we deal with it?
3. If you look at the outputs for Vehicle 4, the start depot is R, but the first edge visited by the vehicle is given as Q-S, then S-T, and then Q-R and so on. But if you look at the NetworkX graph, if the vehicle starts from Node R, then the first visited edge will have to be Q-R (or R-Q). In our case, Q-R is the 3rd edge that the vehicle is visiting. How can we make sure that from depot R, the first edge that the vehicle need to travel through is Q-R before it traverses the later edges? To put more context, let's say R-Q doesn't have any weights, but Q-P has a weight, the vehicle will definitely visit Q-P to pickup the weights but it cannot directly go to Q-P from R, before that it should pass through R-Q. So the ideal route in this case, if the vehicle starts from depot R will be R-Q-P. How can I model this constraint and what changes do I need to perform to ensure that vehicles can only travel to adjacent nodes or adjacent edges?
4. Also how can we prioritize the edges? For example, consider this scenario, a vehicle starts from Node A, it can either take the path A-B-C-D-E-.. or it can take another path A-B-C-AD-AE. Let's say decide to give higher priority to edge D-E over edge AD-AE, so the vehicle will be forced to clear the waste in the route A-B-C-D-E than A-B-C-AD-AE, even if A-B-C-AD-AE has more waste accumulation than A-B-C-D-E.

UPDATE:
Output for a different iteration.

```
Vehicle :  6
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Edge : (AN,AQ), Weight : 1
Edge : (Q,R), Weight : 1
Edge : (N,O), Weight : 1
Edge : (AM,AN), Weight : 3
Edge : (C,AD), Weight : 1
Edge : (V,AU), Weight : 1
Edge : (AM,AV), Weight : 1
Edge : (AN,AO), Weight : 1
Edge : (AB,AC), Weight : 1
Edge : (G,U), Weight : 8
Edge : (AH,AK), Weight : 1
Edge : (I,J), Weight : 1
Edge : (AR,AS), Weight : 1
Edge : (S,T), Weight : 1
Edge : (Q,S), Weight : 1
Visited Edges :  [('AN', 'AQ'), ('Q', 'R'), ('N', 'O'), ('AM', 'AN'), ('C', 'AD'), ('V', 'AU'), ('AM', 'AV'), ('AN', 'AO'), ('AB', 'AC'), ('G', 'U'), ('AH', 'AK'), ('I', 'J'), ('AR', 'AS'), ('S', 'T'), ('Q', 'S')]
Visited Nodes :  ['AN', 'AQ', 'Q', 'R', 'N', 'O', 'AM', 'AN', 'C', 'AD', 'V', 'AU', 'AM', 'AV', 'AN', 'AO', 'AB', 'AC', 'G', 'U', 'AH', 'AK', 'I', 'J', 'AR', 'AS', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'S']
Vehicle Route :  ['R', 'Q', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'L', 'K', 'J', 'I', 'H', 'G', 'U', 'V', 'AU', 'AT', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AQ']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  24
```

[image: Visited Edge Lists by Vehicle]

[image: Predicted Path]

If you look at the above outputs, you will see that the visited edges by vehicle 6 are not adjacent to each other. What might be possibly wrong in the implementation? Because, since it's a graph network, it's assumed that the vehicle will traverse node by node. ar travel only through adjacent nodes.

**EDIT : 10th Jan, 2023.**

I have executed the latest code present at this [GIST](https://here%20https://gist.github.com/Christopher-Chianelli/fae8dfb8676f381157fbc4a65cb4a63a), and I am analyzing the output with the below code. I am not sure if I am interpreting the results correctly or not using the below piece of code. Can you let me know if I am following the right way to get the results? If not, what changes would you suggest to make in the code?

```
ctr = 1    
for vehicle in solution.get_vehicle_list():
    print("Vehicle : ", ctr)
    ctr += 1
    print("Depot : ", vehicle.depot)
    print("Vehicle Capacity : ", vehicle.capacity)
    print("Visited Edge List : ", vehicle.visited_edges_list)
    print()
```

OUTPUT :

```
Final Score --------------------------- 
0hard/83medium/-250soft
Vehicle :  1
Depot :  AS
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['F', 'E', 'D', 'C', 'AD']

Vehicle :  2
Depot :  AS
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['T', 'S', 'AA', 'K']

Vehicle :  3
Depot :  A
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['AE', 'AF', 'AG']

Vehicle :  4
Depot :  A
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['B', 'A', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AX', 'AW', 'AV', 'AT']

Vehicle :  5
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['G', 'U', 'V', 'AU']

Vehicle :  6
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  25
Visited Edge List :  ['Q', 'R', 'J', 'I', 'H', 'AR', 'AQ', 'AN', 'AM', 'AL', 'AK', 'AH', 'AO', 'AP', 'W', 'X', 'AB', 'AC', 'Z', 'Y', 'P', 'O', 'N', 'L', 'M', 'AS']
```

If you look at the above outputs for all the vehicles, the nodes are not ordered yet. Attaching the visited nodes for Vehicle 4 & 6 below for your reference.

[image: Vehicle 4 Route]

[image: Vehicle 6 Route]

Questions :

1. Based on your experience, is 60 seconds enough for solving this particular instance of the Graph with 50 nodes? Based on the complexity of this problem, any guesstimate?
2. What changes would you suggest on top of your gist, so that for every vehicle, it will move only across adjacent nodes?
3. If you look at the outputs, for each depot, none of the vehicle starts from that particular depot. Same with vehicle 4 and 6 as well if you look at the diagrams. What would you recommend in this scenario?

Comment: There are two user issues, and one optapy implementation bug in your code. The first user issue is all planning_list_variable MUST NOT be None, even for the input problem. This can be fixed by setting it to a new empty list if visited_edges_list is None (Note: DO NOT use an empty list as a default parameter value, as that will give the same empty list to all instances). In `Vehicle.__init__(...)`, use this to set the visited_edges_list: `self.visited_edges_list = [] if visited_edges_list is None else visited_edges_list`. (continued...)

Comment: The second user issue is NetworkInfo refers to the graph as `network`, when the constraint refer to it as `graph`. It can be fixed by changing `network` to `graph` in `NetworkInfo`. The optapy implementation bug has to do with `float('inf')`. The `str` constructor for floats has not been implemented in the Python to Java translator, so it will raise an exception about `str` not having `__float__`. Tracking issue is https://github.com/optapy/optapy/issues/134. You can set it to a sufficiently large number (like 999999999.999) as a workaround.

Comment: Once those three changes are implemented, OptaPy will solve the problem. It appears networkx code is sufficiently complex to cause translation to fail, so the code will be slow (at least in CPython 3.11; all CPython versions have different bytecode). I'll investigate later to see if I can fix the translation.

Comment: For 1., distance matrices are handled by the user. It depends on if networkx automatically caches them or not. If `networkx` does not automatically cache the result, you might want to store it in `NetworkInfo` to use in your constraint. For 2., `visited_edges_list` should be an empty list, with each planning entity having a UNIQUE empty list. By default, all vehicles can visit all edges. If certain vehicles can only visit certain edges, consider using https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/planner-configuration/planner-configuration.html#valueRangeProviderOnPlanningEntity

Comment: Hello Christopher. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Can you please tell me how should I add the below constraints in the code:

Comment: 1. In addition to the shortest distance constraints that you have mentioned, can you please provide an implementation details if we want to maximize the volume of waste collection?

Comment: 2. Also, let's say that the vehicle (let's say has a carrying capacity of 30 units of waste), now after it has traversed few nodes and the vehicle has reached it's maximum carrying capacity, it should automatically go to the nearest dumping zone and dump the waste. Can you please provide an implementation for this using shadow variables? I couldn't find any specific tutorial to do the same.

Comment: 3. Also, how can we ensure that a vehicle that starts from a depot will return back to that same depot only?

Comment: 4. And how can I ensure that vehicles will travel to their adjacent nodes only? For example, if a vehicle start from Node A, it can only travel to Node B and not Node C. If the vehicle has to go to Node C, it has to mandatorily pass through Node B. So the vehicle should only travel between nodes which has direct edge between them.

Comment: 1. The constraint would basically be the same as `over_capacity`, but it will not have a filter and it will be a `reward('maximize weight', HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, get_vehicle_total_weight)` instead of a `penalize`. 2. OptaPy currently uses the old Shadow Variable API which does not support List Variables (OptaPlanner new shadow variable API does support List Variables), so I would need to significantly change the domain to give an example. 3. That a built-in constraint (the last item in the list is the final visit, which is NOT a depot).

Comment: 4. It can be modelled as a hard constraint: constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle).filter(is_invalid_path).penalize('invalid path', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD), where is_invalid_path look like this: {current = vehicle.depot; for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list: { if edge.graph_from_node != current: {return True} current = edge.graph_to_node} return False}

Comment: Hello Christopher. Can you kindly provide an implementation example or a workaround on how to model this problem, if we need to execute point 2? Since OptaPy does not support the list variables.

Comment: I wanted to know, how to model the problem in such a way so that we can visualize the solution? I have posted the code in a new answer section. Would it be kindly possible you to connect with me for 30 minutes? Would be extremely helpful and I would get few clarity over this. My email ID : saugata.paul1010@gmail.com

Comment: OptaPy does support list variables, but not shadow variables for list variables; that will be added later

Comment: I have updated my code in the above answer, there are few problems that I am currently facing in the output. I have added questions 1-4. Can you kindly check and let me know how to implement these changes?

Comment: For 1. What is the score of the solution? I expect it to be infeasible (i.e. have a negative hard score), this means you need to give the solver more time/improve score calculation speed (or the problem has no feasible solution, but I think that unlikely). 2. This is where score types come in. See https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#scoreTerminology and https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#scoreType.

Comment: 3. I strongly suspect the above solution have a negative hard score, which means it is invalid; force_adjacent_nodes should accomplish it. 4. With a constraint that penalizes/rewards taking/avoiding those edges on a higher level than waste accumulation (see answer to 2.)

Comment: Can you please provide an implementation in OptaPy for 2 and 4?

Comment: For 10 minutes of solver time and 6 vehicles, the score is -20hard/4soft. It started with -23hard/23 soft. For 120 minutes and 12 vehicles it's -5hard/8soft. Is there any efficient way to assess how much time does a solver might need?

Comment: In regards to 2 & 4, you need to pick a Score type that suites your need (for three levels, HardMediumSoftScore, for 4+ levels, BendableScore. Update the `@planning_score` to use that Score Type, and make ALL constraints use that Score Type (change HardSoftScore.ofHard(...) to HardMediumSoftScore.ofHard(...)). Solve time depends on 1. how efficient your constraints are, 2. the size of your problem space, and 3. the Solver configuration. The constraints can probably be improved speed wise, and if you have multiple cores, you can enable multithreaded solving.

Comment: In OptaPlanner, another way to improve performance is to implement your own moves and move selectors, which take your constraints into considerations (for example, a bulk move that moves all processes on one computer to another computer). OptaPy does not support custom moves yet, but will in a future version.

Comment: I have tried with all the variations of planning_score, and the best I could reach was a -2 hard. Even when I am using 1 constraint, the hard score doesn't seem to be zero. I have run the solver for more than 10 hours. What might be the fix for this?

Comment: With regards to 4, what I mean is suppose we say on a given day edges A-B, E-F, and AX-AW should be prioritized. So these 3 edges will be an input to the solution. Based on this  input, the vehicle will make sure that it must and must include these edges when clearing the waste, even if volume of waste present is low in all these 3 edges, since they are explicitly mentioned as inputs, the vehicles will make sure to include these edges. How can I handle this?

Comment: I have updated my latest code, can you kindly run this once at your end, so that you can reproduce the solution and check the output for the issues that I have mentioned. If you check the outputs for visited edges by a vehicle, they are not ordered or adjacent. What might possibly wrong in the implementation so that this is not giving expected results?

Comment: Then to implement 4, use pinning: https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/repeated-planning/repeated-planning.html#pinnedPlanningEntities ; `@planning_list_variable` do not support pinning yet though, so you would need to use a chained model to implement it.

Comment: The problem with the hard score is from `is_invalid_path`, looking at your graph, some clusters of nodes are accessible only via a single edge, meaning if two dumping trucks need to reach the same cluster of nodes, it is impossible for both to have a valid path (in `planning_list_variable`, no items (in this case, edges) are shared. I would update the model to use nodes instead, and do a soft/medium penalty if consecutive nodes are not connected by an edge

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/Christopher-Chianelli/fae8dfb8676f381157fbc4a65cb4a63a ; it still need to be modified a bit (in particular, you need duplicate node objects, one for every time the node appears in an edge), additionally, it comes with a performance improvement for minimize_distance, since it does not recalculate shortest path every time.

Comment: Thanks for providing the latest update on the implementation, however, the node issues still persists, I am posting my question as an EDIT. As an alternative, I have also used Floyd Marshall for calculating the distance matrices, but there's no effect on the output. Ran the solver for 60 seconds to get a score of - 0hard/83medium/-250soft.

Comment: Do you think this issue persists because of the fact that the duplicate node objects are not created? I am not sure from that implementation point of view what are the things I need to do. Can you please provide me a implementation reference for the same? It would be good if you can kindly share some references to implement the one that you have mentioned.

Comment: Since this is becoming an extended discussion, let continue it on Zulip: https://kie.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/232679-optaplanner/topic/Solving.20VRP.20using.20OptaPy.20and.20NetworkX.2E/near/319566879

Answer (score 0):

How can I visualize the solution? For example, I have used the below code to solve the problem, but is there any way we can visualize the results. The output results should contain the path for the optimal vehicle routes and the volume of sand that is cleared in the path.

Expected Output:

Vehicle 1 Route: A - B - C - D - E - F 
Vehicle 1 Waste cleared : 16 Units

Vehicle 2 Route: AS - AJ - AH -  AK - AL - AM - AW - AQ 
Vehicle 2 Waste cleared : 3 Units

```
from optapy.types import Duration
from optapy import solver_factory_create

solver_config = optapy.config.solver.SolverConfig()
solver_config.withSolutionClass(VRPSolution).withEntityClasses(Vehicle).withConstraintProviderClass(vehicle_routing_constraints).withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
solution = solver_factory_create(solver_config).buildSolver().solve(problem)
print(solution)

ctr = 1
for vehicle in solution.get_vehicle_list():
    print("Vehicle : ", ctr)
    ctr += 1
    print("Depot : ", vehicle.depot)
    print("Vehicle Capacity : ", vehicle.capacity)
    edges  = vehicle.visited_edges_list
    
    route_path = []
    total_weight = []
    
    for edge in edges:
        print("Edge : {}-{}, Weight : {}".format(edge.graph_from_node, edge.graph_to_node, edge.weight))     
        route_path.append(edge.graph_from_node)
        total_weight.append(edge.weight)

    print("Vehicle Route : ", route_path)
    print("Total Weight of Collected Waste : ", sum(total_weight))
    print()
```

Output :

```
Vehicle :  1
Depot :  AJ
Vehicle Capacity :  15
Edge : AI-AJ, Weight : 1
Edge : AK-AL, Weight : 3
Edge : AL-AM, Weight : 1
Edge : AM-AN, Weight : 3
Edge : AN-AQ, Weight : 1
Edge : AR-AS, Weight : 1
Edge : AM-AV, Weight : 1
Edge : AT-AU, Weight : 1
Edge : V-W, Weight : 1
Edge : W-X, Weight : 1
Edge : AB-AC, Weight : 1
Edge : X-Y, Weight : 1
Edge : Y-Z, Weight : 1
Edge : Z-AA, Weight : 1
Edge : X-AB, Weight : 1
Edge : V-AU, Weight : 1
Edge : AT-AV, Weight : 1
Vehilce Route :  ['AI', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AR', 'AM', 'AT', 'V', 'W', 'AB', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'V', 'AT']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  21

Vehicle :  2
Depot :  AJ
Vehicle Capacity :  10
Edge : AF-AG, Weight : 15
Edge : AN-AO, Weight : 1
Vehilce Route :  ['AF', 'AN']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  16

Vehicle :  3
Depot :  A
Vehicle Capacity :  7
Edge : A-B, Weight : 1
Edge : C-AD, Weight : 1
Edge : C-D, Weight : 5
Vehilce Route :  ['A', 'C', 'C']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  7

Vehicle :  4
Depot :  A
Vehicle Capacity :  15
Edge : B-C, Weight : 2
Edge : AE-AF, Weight : 10
Edge : AD-AE, Weight : 1
Edge : AG-AH, Weight : 1
Edge : AH-AI, Weight : 1
Edge : AH-AK, Weight : 1
Edge : AO-AP, Weight : 1
Edge : AQ-AR, Weight : 1
Edge : AV-AW, Weight : 4
Vehilce Route :  ['B', 'AE', 'AD', 'AG', 'AH', 'AH', 'AO', 'AQ', 'AV']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  22

Vehicle :  5
Depot :  G
Vehicle Capacity :  10
Edge : D-E, Weight : 7
Edge : AW-AX, Weight : 6
Edge : E-AX, Weight : 1
Edge : F-G, Weight : 1
Vehilce Route :  ['D', 'AW', 'E', 'F']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  15

Vehicle :  6
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  5
Edge : P-Q, Weight : 1
Edge : E-F, Weight : 4
Vehilce Route :  ['P', 'E']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  5

Vehicle :  7
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  15
Edge : I-J, Weight : 1
Edge : J-K, Weight : 1
Edge : K-L, Weight : 1
Edge : L-M, Weight : 1
Edge : L-N, Weight : 1
Edge : N-O, Weight : 1
Edge : J-P, Weight : 1
Edge : U-V, Weight : 9
Vehilce Route :  ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'L', 'N', 'J', 'U']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  16

Vehicle :  8
Depot :  R
Vehicle Capacity :  10
Edge : Q-R, Weight : 1
Edge : Q-S, Weight : 1
Edge : S-T, Weight : 1
Edge : O-P, Weight : 1
Edge : G-U, Weight : 8
Edge : G-H, Weight : 1
Edge : H-I, Weight : 1
Vehilce Route :  ['Q', 'Q', 'S', 'O', 'G', 'G', 'H']
Total Weight of Collected Waste :  14
```

Here, if you look at the solution for each vehicle, we get the list of edges visited by those vehicles, if we take an example of Vehicle 8, the vehicle should start from Node R (which is the depot), the vehicle will visit these edges -- Q-R, Q-S, S-T, O-P, G-U, G-H, H-I. But what I am looking for is the optimal path of each vehicle such that they cover all the list of visited edges. Is there any other way, we should model the problem to get the exact routes?

Also, is there any way to model the problem in a way, in which the vehicle will start from Node R, collect all the waste till it's capacity has reached, and then it will go to the dumping zone to drop the waste?

Let's stay, a vehicle starts from Node R. Based on the waste accumulation, let's say it traverses this path -- R - Q - O - N - L - K - J. Let's say that at Node J, the vehicle capacity will max out, then it should check from J which is the nearest dumping zone. The vehicle will see that F is the nearest dumping zone, so it will go to F, dump the waste and re-start it's operation from F. Let's say from F, the vehicle takes another path -- F - G - U - V - W - X. Let's say that the same vehicles capacity is maxied out at X. Then it will see thay the nearest dumping zone from Z is AA, hence it will go there and dump the waste. Now if there's no longer waste left to be cleaned, the vehicle can get back to it's starting position which is R.

Can you kindly check if the implementation for point 4 is correct? I have created this function called force_adjacent_nodes() in which my primary goal is to ensure that vehicles will travel to their adjacent nodes only? For example, if a vehicle start from Node A, it can only travel to Node B and not Node C. If the vehicle has to go to Node C, it has to mandatorily pass through Node B. So the vehicle should only travel between nodes which has direct edge between them.

```
def is_invalid_path(vehicle: Vehicle):
    current = vehicle.depot
    for edge in vehicle.visited_edges_list:
        if edge.graph_from_node != current: 
            return True
        elif current == edge.graph_to_node:
            return False
    
def force_adjacent_nodes(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return(
        constraint_factory.for_each(Vehicle)
        .filter(lambda vehicle: is_invalid_path(vehicle))
        .penalize('invalid path', HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
        )

@optapy.constraint_provider
def vehicle_routing_constraints(constraint_factory: ConstraintFactory):
    return [
        over_capacity(constraint_factory),
        minimize_distance(constraint_factory),
        maximize_weight(constraint_factory),
        force_adjacent_nodes(constraint_factory)
    ]
```

While implementing the above changes, I am getting below error:

```
RuntimeError: An error occurred during solving. This can occur when functions take the wrong number of parameters (ex: a setter that does not take exactly one parameter) or by a function returning an incompatible return type (ex: returning a str in a filter, which expects a bool). This can also occur when an exception is raised when evaluating constraints/getters/setters.
```

Wanted to check what am I missing or doing wrong from an implementation point of view? I can provide the updated code in a new answer section for your reference.

Comment: the problem is with is_invalid_path; it MUST always return a boolean (True or False), never None (as written above, it return None on a valid path). change `elif current == edge.graph_to_node` to `current = edge.graph_to_node` and unindent `return False` (should be outside the for loop scope).